# Capture and send specific visible tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

in my `background.js` i will capture a specific area in a div.

My code looks like

```
function main()
{
    chrome.tabs.query( {'active': true}, check_tab );
}
function check_tab( tabs )
{
    for (i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) { 
        var url = tabs[i].url;
        if ( -1 < url.indexOf( "https://www.specificurl" ) ) {
            chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab( null, {'format': "png"}, function(img){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://mywebsite.com/doSomething.php",
                    data: "img=" + img
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I would like `crop the image and send` or `send image with position, width and height to cut`. Whether it's the first case or the second case, I need access to the position, the width and height of the div to cut correctly. How can I get the source code of the webpage by `chrome.tabs` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the html of current page, use `var html = $('html').html();` or `document.documentElement.innerHTML`

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {"code": "var html = document.documentElement.innerHTML;"}, function(html) {
    console.log(html); 
});
```

Take a look at this [open source project](https://github.com/khuevu/social-snap), it allows you to capture selected area in a web page, the basic idea would be using canvas to draw the image, then you can crop the canvas with specific position, width and height.

Comment: I tried it with a similar project ( [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) ) but it does not work because I want to make a screenshot of a Flash display.

The problem is that the code is in the chrome extension, I can not do that `html = $('html').html();`

Comment: @Rodrigue To use `var html = $('html').html();` you'll need to use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)

Comment: @dan75, I have edited the answer, you could use content script or just use programming injection to get the current DOM.

Comment: Nice tips but i can't execute a script after loading loading the page. I want to receive information of a div every x seconds.. But i can't.

Comment: @Rodrigue, I'd suggest starting another post with more details( manifest file, and etc), since it seems they are two different questions.